# Merge columns selectively in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, multiple-columns, columnsorting

I have the following columns in Excel: date, status, latitude, longitude, cases. Then the last three (lat, long, cases) repeat hundreds of times. How to merge to have only 5 columns?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeCdW.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `SUMIF` formula:

```
=SUMIF($D$1:$O$1,"Latitude",D2:O2)
```

[image]

or if your purpose is to merge then use `TEXTJOIN`

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(" ",true,IF($D$1:$O$1="Latitude",D2:O2,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this is not it. My bad. Here is a better explanation of what I need. Need to have Latitude and corresponding Longitude and Cases (Other), and the date copied/pasted under last cells with data. For example, columns data from D(lat) E(long), F(cases) fulfilled with data from G, H, I and A (date) starting at the first empty cells: A303, D303, E303, F303. Then A, J, K, L to go under and so on. It would have only 5 columns: A-date, B-Status, C-lat, D-long, E-cases. I don't think it can be done without VBA Code.